# Update an existing column with data from another using a trigger on a view

Tags: sql, postgresql, moodle

I have a query that I run to pull data from multiple tables which are part of the Questionnaire plugin Moodle.

This returns a view. (Joining this view to another for php search)
What I would like is for a column `app_ref` which has a ref number inserted into it to copy to another column `ref_number` in the same view.

```
ref_number|app_ref
            1234
            2345
```

I have googled and I understand I need to use a trigger  but I have never used a trigger/constructed one (learning PostgreSQL) so I'm not sure as having read on the [PostgreSQL site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html), would the trigger run BEFORE or AFTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update a view which is not updatable because it selects from more than one table.

First, you can write a procedure that executes the update you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_view_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

-- Here comes your SQL to handle your ref_number and app_ref issue
-- use NEW.app_ref or OLD.app_ref to access values

RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
```

You can then tell the view to execute your function instead of the "update" like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_update 
  INSTEAD OF UPDATE
  ON my_view
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_view_update;
```